# Is there jave ee contract implementation?

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee, jdbc, webserver

Like on jdbc java provide an interfaces, I see the interfaces like a contract for implementers (Drivers from multiple vendor) to implement those interfaces with respect to their documented functionality from java.

But on java ee, and based on this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7571260/revisions

It's the same case on jave ee, the application servers are vendors and they implement jave ee abstract API, but on jdbc (And I mentioned it just as an example) the interfaces on java.sql package define the contract, but on jave ee(for example HttpServlet class) where is the interface the defines the general rules from java to this class that application server have to implement? 
or is there any external agreements among application servers to implement the functionality of java ee classes?
Or java ee doc (like on 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/
)
is adopted as an agreement?

Some people will see my question is useless, but I want to know the root of any stuff I want to learn, and my mind is used to answer small deal questions.

Comment: What's a "small deal question"?

Comment: google it you could find such ansewer, and save some others time of typing the answer of known question.
it's not important question, you know what question mean then "small deal" meaning is
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Small+Deal

Answer (score 1):

There are test suites that the vendor implementations are tested against, which obviously need to pass. The [specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) also need to be obeyed to be a valid Java EE implementation. The Javadoc API is not the spec, but rather a side effect of it.

Comment: Even for JDBC the specification is not only the JDBC apidoc (or the interfaces).